# Unhandled Exception: '!_debugLocked': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator

When I click on an expandable listtile by tapping on the listtile, this error is thrown through the following code.

I've not been able to figure out how to resolve it.

Thanks, here is the comprehensive code. So please, take a look at the whole below. The initial post was flagged for conataining 'mostly code', which is why I trimmed it.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        // appBar: AppBar(
        //   title: Text('Checklist'),
        //   centerTitle: true,
        // ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ExpansionPanelList.radio(
            expansionCallback: (index, isExpanded) {
              final tile = advancedTiles[index];
              setState(() => tile.isExpanded = isExpanded);

              Utils.showSnackBar(
                context,
                text: isExpanded
                    ? 'Shrink ${tile.title}'
                    : 'Expand ${tile.title}',
                color: Colors.green,
              );
            },

            
            children: advancedTiles
                .map((tile) => ExpansionPanelRadio(
                      value: tile.title,
                      canTapOnHeader: true,
                      headerBuilder: (context, isExpanded) => buildTile(tile),
                      body: Column(
                        children: tile.tiles.map(buildTile).toList(),
                      ),
                    ))
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      );

    
  Widget buildTile(AdvancedTile tile) => ListTile(
        // leading: tile.icon != null ? Icon(tile.icon) : null,
        title: Text(tile.title,  
        style: TextStyle(
          // color:  Colors.white, 
        // fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, 
        fontSize: 18),
        ),
        
        onTap: tile.tiles.isEmpty
            ? () => Utils.showSnackBar(
                  context,
                  text: 'Clicked on: ${tile.title}',
                  color: Colors.green,
                )
            : null,
      );
}
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted as well as up voting it. :-)

Comment: Btw, what ide or editor are you using to write your code? Pretty sure VSCode would have highlighted that error.

Comment: VS Code. I think it has something to do with the navigator, but I dont know how to fix the syntax.

Comment: This. is the error its showin now ```E/flutter (22191): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 5094 pos 14: 'entry.currentState == _RouteLifecycle.popping': is not true.```

Comment: You need to show more of you code after your latest changes.

Comment: Ok, I've just updated it with the full code.

Comment: If that is the code you are running then the onTap syntax is still wrong. Please compare my code and yours carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Your ontap syntax is wrong. Try

```
onTap: () => tile.tiles.isEmpty
            ? Utils.showSnackBar(
                  context,
                  text: 'Clicked on: ${tile.title}',
                  color: Colors.green,
                )
            : null,
```